# Updating column in layer with NULL currently to nearby value in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, fields-attributes, proximity

Currently I have a layer with construction year attributes in it. Not all of these are filled out and I figure it is reasonable to update them with the construction year of the nearby elements as they would all be constructed around the same time typically.

How do I do this given that I would be taking values from the same table and assigning them using intersecting/crossing/contains?

I am using QGIS 2.6.0 Brighton.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do a spatial join. You can find the tool in the vector menu or in the processing toolbox. After doing this join you can use the field calculator in order to say that the column X with the date is equal to the column Y that you want to populate.

Comment: Spatial joins seem to not work within the layer (and it saves another layer)

Comment: Spatial joins are not present in the Vector Menu and in the Processing Toolbox as that name. They are under Join by Location. This does not operate within a layer but creates a whole new layer and affects all of them which I do not want.

This is as far as I'm aware anyway.

Comment: You could try a workaround that I don't know if it'll work for your situation but here we go. If the layer with the attribute that you want is near by, you could try to: 
- buffer your construction shape
- then you intersect the buffer with the near by elements. This way you will have a new shape with the information you want
- then you could join the new shape with the construction layer using a common attribute
- finally use field calculator to say that the original year field is = to intersection year field.
Let me know if this works!